# Implementing trie for efficient search of products on my website

Tags: algorithm, search, javascript, trie

I have got a list of say million of products. Now when the user at my website types something, I need to show him some relevant products for help. The search should be fast. I think trie implementation will be fine for me.

But i am confused with the very idea of implementation. I need to have the tree ready always , so that i can search n show the result instantaneously. If i start inserting the elements while calling the javascript function , it will take too long.

Can anyone suggest me, what am i missing ? My aim is to show **fast** out of a list of **MILLIONS**

Thanks :)

Comment: The usual way to solve this problem would be to have a database table with millions of rows and a proper index on it. As soon as the user types, an Ajax request is made and appropriate products are fetched via SQL and sent to the client to display. Is there anything that speaks against this approach?

Comment: hmm...then i will do the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you have a sidebar on the right where the relevant products need to be shown.

The user types in the search and only the first X products are displayed in the right (let's say first 50 products). Also there will be a "Display more products" link at the bottom of that list. Twitter for example uses this approach.

Even if there are 1 milions products available, the user doesn't need to see them all in the same time, so making an Ajax request for a) the first X products and b) the number of total products (so you know if a 'Display more' link is required) is perfect.

When the user clicks on 'Display more' you'll display another X products and so on.

Comment: Hey, I implemented the same for my search bar. But the problem is that, the AJAX request takes me approx 1.5 s to fetch the result. I think everyone types faster than that, so its of no use ??

Any reason for the sluggish response ??

here it is http://buyhatke.com/search.php

Comment: You need to optimize your server side (& database).

Comment: Even, if i just printed Hello from my server side, it took me 1.3 s , thats too much. I don't know why :(

Comment: It's a problem with your server then, sorry.