# How to handle large amounts of data memory-efficiently in JS

Tags: javascript, memory

While trying to handle offline StarDict dictionaries in JavaScript, I came across strange memory consumption behaviour of JavaScript (tested in Gecko, i.e. Firefox 27).

Actually, I have a StarDict file *.syn of about 6.2 MB containing 313,608 uncompressed UTF-8 encoded strings plus some extra data. Then I use the code below to load this into my JavaScript as an array of 313,608 strings.

I end up with appx. 48 MB of memory consumption. (Checked with about:memory; remember we started with 6.2 MB!) This value goes down to 37 MB when switching tabs and waiting for a few minutes. JavaScript works with UTF-16 internally, so the worst I expected was appx. 15 MB. But it's more than twice that much! I have no idea, what might have caused this and I don't know what to do in order to handle this amount of data in JavaScript more efficiently. Please give advice!

**The code** or **How to reproduce this**

Put this somewhere in your HTML's body:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Then use this JavaScript onload code:

```
function getUintAt(arr, offs) {
    out = 0;
    for (var j = offs; j < offs+4; j++) {
            out <<= 8;
            out |= arr[j] & 0xff;
    }
    return out;
}

var arr = [],
    upload = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

upload.onchange = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var file = evt.target.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        var buffer = evt.target.result,
            view = new Uint8Array(buffer),
            decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
        for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
            if(view[i] == 0) {
                var term = decoder.decode(view.subarray(j,i)),
                    extra = getUintAt(view, i+1);
                arr.push({ term: term, extra: extra });
                i += 5; j = i;
            }
        }
        console.log(arr.length);
    };
};
```

and chose the *.syn file from http://tovotu.de/data/pape_gr-de.zip for the file input element. You may test with similar StarDict dictionaries (i.e. that have big syn files!) and will get similar results: Processing a syn-file of size X? JavaScript will need about 7 or 8 times as much.

Comment: that may help http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2009/12/javascript-array-performance-and-why-it-matters/#comments

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be about arrays but about strings. A big part (appx. 20 MB) comes from js-zone -> strings/normal, while js-compartment -> objects allocates another ~20 MB. Since 20 MB is a reasonable size for that data, it seems like it's allocating double the strings' size to "simplify string concatenation".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing trie for efficient search of products on my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464444/implementing-trie-for-efficient-search-of-products-on-my-website)

Comment: No, it's definitely not a duplicate of that question, because here we are talking about pure offline stuff. All of this code has to work offline, even the data itself is provided by the user offline - possibly in an offline environment where there is not even the possibility to connect to any servers.